# Linux VPS harddisk showing 390 GB data out of 500GB

Tags: vps

My Linux VPS harddisk showing 390GB data used out of 500GB, but when i see in my whm panel its showing only 22GB harddisk used, how can i check and solve the problem. Please find the attached image also.

[whm panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDDf2.png)
[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gspRT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the VHD (virtual hard disk) container in your windows machine, not the disk usage value from inside the virtual machine.

The value in windows there is like looking on the front of a physical hard disk and reading "capacity: 500GB".
In the control panel, that's value is being called from inside the virtual machine, if you SSH into your virtual machine and run "df -h" it'll give you the correct usage as according to the virtual server itself.

The value in the windows machine is the size of the virtual machines entire hard disk drive.